# PHP $_FILES returns a string when I want an image file

Tags: php, html, ftp

I'm trying to upload an image file to FileZilla(in XAMPP) from a form post, however something's not going right. Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Image: <br><input type="file" name="image" required>
<input type="submit">
```

There are also some textareas in the form. So I input everything and select my picture, then everything is given to handler.php...

```
$image = $_FILES["image"]['tmp_name'];

$ftpCon = ftp_connect("127.0.0.1", "21") or die("Could not connect to FTP");
ftp_fput($ftpCon, "image.png", $image, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($ftpCon);
```

That code gives me the message "ftp_fput() expects parameter 3 to be resource, string given"
and when I echo it, it is the path of the temp file, ex: E:\xampp\tmp\phpE62C.tmp

Also, that is the whole of my code concerning ftp, so I could be missing something, as this is the first time I've worked with ftp.

Comment: Duplicate of the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php

Comment: Use `ftp_put` instead of `ftp_fput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

Open the temporary file and pass the resource to `ftp_fput`:

```
$image_fd = fopen($image, "r");
ftp_fput($ftpCon, "image.png", $image_fd, FTP_BINARY);
fclose($image_fd);
```

Pass the filename to `ftp_put`:

```
ftp_put($ftpCon, "image.png", $image, FTP_BINARY);
```